# Why do 1920x1080p videos still get stretched and distorted after I concat them?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have several videos with different aspect ratios.

I use this command to put them all within a 1920x1080p frame:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -strict experimental output
```

This works and all videos keep their aspect ratios while being in a 1080p resolution.

After that its done, I concat them with this and I see two unexpected behaviors:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i videolist.txt -vcodec libx264 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -strict experimental -c copy 1080p_merged\output.mp4
```

First, the vertical videos get stretched horizontally, even though they are already in a 1920x1080p frame while keeping their aspect ratio. How is this possible?

And second, I see the frame rate get down from 30fps, which i set in every instance (the original videos also have 30fps, to 29.95 or 29.81 or something.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you're re-encoding your video, twice. That will affect video quality. If you do the first step properly, you might not need to re-encode in the second step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the weird aspect ratio is related to the SAR - [Sample Aspect Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio).

Usually the SAR is 1:1, applying square pixels.
SAR value that is not 1:1 applies non-squered pixels.
You first command modifies the SAR property, and that is the cause for the weird results.

---

Let's start by building few synthetic video samples:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=320x240:rate=30:duration=5 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 in1.mkv
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x120:rate=30:duration=5 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 in2.mkv
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=240x320:rate=30:duration=5 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 in3.mkv
```

---

Convert the resolution to 1920x1080 using your command:

```
ffmpeg -i in1.mkv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -i in2.mkv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out2.mp4
ffmpeg -i in3.mkv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out3.mp4
```

---

Query `width`, `height`, `SAR` and `DAR` [using FFprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091550/4926757):

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 in1.mkv
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 in2.mkv
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 in3.mkv

ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 out1.mp4
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 out2.mp4
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 out3.mp4
```

FFprobe output:

```
in1.mkv
width=320
height=240
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=4:3

in2.mkv
width=640
height=120
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:3

in3.mkv
width=240
height=320
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=3:4

out1.mp4
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=3:4
display_aspect_ratio=4:3

out2.mp4
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=3:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:3

out3.mp4
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=27:64
display_aspect_ratio=3:4
```

As you can see, the SAR of the input videos is `1:1` but the SAR of the output videos is affected by the resolution of the original input video.

The fact that the SAR is not `1:1` causes weird aspect ratio issues.
Note: I don't know why the default of FFmpeg to modify the SAR, but that is how it works.

---

For solving it, you may use `scale` filter with `setsar` filter as described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling):

```
ffmpeg -y -i in1.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in2.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out2.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in3.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 out3.mp4
```

---

FFprobe output:

```
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9

width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9

width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
```

Now the SAR is `1:1` and the DAR is `16:9`.

You may concatenate the above files, without getting modified aspect ratio.

---

**Fixing the FPS:**

The average FPS is an estimation, and there is more than one reason for inaccuracies.
It hard to say the reason for the minor inaccuracies.

According to the concat demuxer [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-concat-1):

> All files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc.)

We may try replacing `-r 30` with [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1) filter (set timebase, and fix the timetaps just in case...):

```
ffmpeg -y -i in1.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,fps=fps=30,settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in2.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,fps=fps=30,settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 out2.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in3.mkv -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,fps=fps=30,settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 out3.mp4
```

I am not sure if it is going to solve the FPS issue.

---

Note:
Preparing the input files and then re-encoding is not the best solution, because you are re-encoding the videos twice, and loosing quality.

I recommend you to use [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-concat), instead of concat demuxer, and do it all in a single command (in case it's not too difficult).

Comment: Thanks Rotem, I am trying those atm, the fps sissue persists. I did concat videos in total lengeth of 13 mins together, suddenly the videos is supposedly over 2 hrs long, can't scroll through or anything... something is not working. will tell u if i could fix it!

Comment: So your Solution had no fps/length issues but the footage was stretched, so i ended up adding adding the parameters of the old command and ended up using this, which works perfectly now, all videos are now in a 1080p frame with no issues at all:

ffmpeg -i SRC-vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=fps=30,settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" DEST

Comment: why can't i mark both answers as "helpful/correct answer since the mix of both ended up helping ./

Comment: @Gramrock: I'm still a new user on this site so to answer your question directly "I do not know" but I saw a few similar situations and then the user who asked the question created his own "best / accepted" combined answer. Here is an info from the Help Center: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

The option `-s 1920x1080` does not define a "frame border" to put these videos in. It defines the resolution of the output video and, indirectly, the expected aspect ratio of the output video is 16:9.

When you are merging the videos with some different aspect ratios they will be stretched to reach the same aspect ratio.

To prevent this you can add some padding (horizontal or vertical black bars) to the input videos in aspect ratios other than 16:9 before scaling them to 1920x1080.

Here are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671252/how-to-add-black-borders-to-video) how to add such black bars.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the other thread and that worked!  Cheers!